# Extract core points from DBSCAN in R

Tags: r, dbscan

Given data below, I have applied DBSCAN on those points

```
set.seed(294056)
df = data.frame(x = runif(1000), y = runif(1000), z = runif(1000))
library(dbscan)
db = dbscan(df, eps = 0.3, minPts =100) # formed 1 cluster
print(db)

DBSCAN clustering for 1000 objects.
Parameters: eps = 0.3, minPts = 100
The clustering contains 1 cluster(s) and 60 noise points.

  0   1 
 60 940 

Available fields: cluster, eps, minPts
```

I wanted to extract core points from that cluster. Is there a way to extract those points?

Comment: You need to use `set.seed(x)` and share so that others can reproduce the same dataset as at your end.

Comment: @tushaR Thanks.. done the edit

Answer (score 1):

In your `dbscan` set `borderPoints = F`.

This way, you only retrieve core points by discarding border points.

Comment: **borderPoints:**

`logical; should border points be assigned. The default is TRUE for regular DBSCAN. If FALSE then border points are considered noise`

This creates different cluster without border points. All I want is to see what all points are assigned as core points in the cluster (with borderPoints = TRUE).

Comment: The dbscan implementation does not keep this information. However, the clustering of core points is stable, so if you run the algorithm once with `borderPoints = TRUE` and once with `borderPoints = FALSE`, then you should get the answer you are looking for.